# Asynchronous calls are not consistent on only Fire Fox

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, firefox

This is Fire Fox only related issue. When I'm using Asynchronous calls FireFox browser will not process requests consistently.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  fn_guardar(i)
}

function fn_guardar(Consecutivo) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "xxxxxx",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      xxxxxxx
    },
    success: function() {
      var url = "http://" + printerIP + "/pstprnt";

      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "post",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        data: zpl,
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          console.log(xhr.status + " - " + thrownError + " - " + xhr.responseText);
          frmDatos.submit();
        },
        success: function() {
          frmDatos.submit();
        }

      })
    }

  });

}
```

I am printing some labels while calling few web services. I'm using **async: fals**e to all waiting processes since if I do not, it will not print correct labels (no of labels and correct data) from the printer. When I use **async: false** all other browsers including Chrome and IE produce very consistent results every time. However in FireFox, results are not consistent. As an example it will print 1 - 3 labels only. sometimes 1,3, 7 sequence.

> FF version : 73.0 (64-bit) (I tried some other FF lower versions as well)

Do you guys have any suggestion ?

Comment: Could you post the `console` error in FF developer tools? I am not exactly sure what their key command is to get to developer tools. Perhaps you can research that then update your post.

Comment: There are no errors in the console. Debugging also not worked.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. There are variables that are nowhere defined, like `printerIP` and `zpl`. Does `Consecutivo` have a function?

Comment: Yeah,, I just included relevant code to here. zpl is my printing data and it is defined in the same function. print Ip is just a printer IP address which also defined. Consecutivo is just a sequence no. it print 1-10 in the labels.

Comment: What browser support are you aiming for? Does it need to support IE?

Comment: IE and the Chrome working perfectly. I need to have a fix for FireFox.